# which one is the better sentence? help me please

Tags: grammar, meaning

I read some books and watched a video lecture and a movie yesterday. The problem is that I did these things on and off. "I have knew my concentration is bad" but yesterday I felt it keenly. How do I fix it?

I read some books and watched a video lecture and a movie yesterday. The problem is that I did these things on and off. "I knew my concentration was bad" but yesterday I felt it keenly. How do I fix it?

I mean, "I have knew my concentration is bad" vs  "I knew my concentration was bad"

Answer (score 1):

`'I knew my concentration was bad'` is the correct one. you'd use 'have' if you were using a different tense, like `'I have always known that my concentration was bad'`